# SourceKitService Crashed in Xcode 6.1.1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, xcode6

I started having an issue with **Xcode 6.0.1** where the error `"SourceKitService Crashed Crashlog generated in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports"` started popping up and all syntax highlighting was gone in Swift. Then Apple released a new update **Xcode 6.1.1** where mentioned this issue was resolved. So I updated my Xcode to 6.1.1 but this problem still exists. I my case the issue is just staying there and never disappearing.

[image]

I tried few solutions found in StackOverflow like deleting the content of: `DerivedData/ModuleCache`, cleaning up the project etc but the issue still exists.

I am not able to make a build and whenever I try to  get these 2 errors.

```
/Users/MY_PROJECT/AppDelegate.swift:11:1: 'UIApplicationMain' class must conform to the 'UIApplicationDelegate'
```

protocol at UIApplicationMain in my AppDelegate.h file and this Command failed due to signal: `Segmentation fault: 11`

Here is the code of my AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication!) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication!) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication!) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication!) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication!) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}


}
```

Comment: In 6.1.1 there are still numerous cases where source kit services can crash.  Have a look at the review section for Xcode in the App Store.  I see several such crashes every day but they don't normally take out the syntax highlighting anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I'am not sure about the cause of this error, i was getting this sourcekit crash for various reasons. For you if you look into `UIApplicationDelegate` methods, they are slightly changed in the signature. For eg `UIApplication` parameter is not optional now.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }
```

So if you compare your delegate methods with new `UIApplicationDelegate` methods(if you command+click you can check the method signature)and make changes you may get rid off this error. Give a try.